# Add option on FullPage.js when screen size is equal to 480 and below

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

I am using fullpage.js for a website I am building and I want to add a normal scroll option on specific section when screen size is equal to 480 or below.
This is my current code.

```
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    autoscrolling: true,
    anchors: ['hero', 'news', 'information', 'activity', 'pictures', 'contact', 'oceanShiga',
        'p-footer'
    ],
    css3: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 1000,
    fitToSection: true,
    dragAndMove: true,
    afterRender:()=>{
        if(window.innerWidth <= 480 ){
            scrollbar:true
        }
        $(window).width() > 480){ 
            $('#fullpage').fullpage(
                normalScrollElements:['hero','news'],
            )
            };
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered on the [fullpage.js isssues forum](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed):

I would recommend you to just listen to the resize event.
When the viewport becomes less than 480px width then you can add a class to those elements, for example .normalScroll.
And when it becomes bigger you can remove it.

To do so you can use the `afterResize` event that fullpage.js provides.

Then you can use this option on fullpage.js initialisation.

```js
new fullpage('#fullpage', {
    normalScrollElements: '.normalScroll',
    afterResize: function(width, height) {
        var normalScrollSelectors = ['.hero', '.news'];
        console.log(width)
        normalScrollSelectors.forEach(function(selector) {
            if (width < 440) {
                document.querySelector(selector).classList.add('normalScroll');
            } else {
                document.querySelector(selector).classList.remove('normalScroll');
            }
        });
    }
})
```

```html
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">
        Section 1
        <div class="news">
           Testing...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Section 2
        <div class="hero">
           Testing...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Section 3</div>
    <div class="section">Section 4</div>
    
</div>
```